# React-Native CLI Unable to boot device in current state: Booted

Tags: ios, react-native, macos

I want run react-native project but when i write 'npx react-native run-ios' I get the following error. After OK button clicking simulator worked. What is this error and how can i solve it?

[image]

I tried many methods but didn't work.

Comment: uh, make sure that the emulator's icon is not showing in the bottom bar, sometimes it gets "stuck" and you need to close it.

Comment: I sure but error continue.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found solution. Simulator -> Preferences -> Simulator lifetime: When Simulator starts boot the most recently used simulator I unchecked.

Comment: Worked great. On my version of Simulator, it is "Settings", not "Preferences", but same otherwise.